# Django-3.2 empty path anchoring in template

Tags: django

I have two urls.py file. The first one on root I have included the second.

#urls.py (project urls file)

```
path('', include('home.urls')),
```

#urls.py (home app urls file)

```
path('', views.Home.as_view(), name='index'),
```

In my browser address bar '127.0.0.1:8000' works just fine. I am getting stuck when I want to anchor the url in template.

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}"></a>
```

Comment: Does your `urls.py` contains an `app_name = '...'`?

Comment: yes, I have added ```app_name = 'home'``` in my apps urls.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got the answer.

#urls.py (home app urls file)

```
app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.Home.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

The template url will be

```
{% url 'home:index' %}
```